# How to use XML document in SQL Server with unknown node elements?

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to insert Excel data into a database. The structure of the Excel data is

```
Service    General    SBI    BOB   
Luxury      300       300    250   
Apartment   200       200    150   
villa       500       400    300
```

It has to be sent to the database in this format

```
Service     Category    Rate

Luxury      General     300 
Luxury        SBI       300
Luxury        BOB       250
Apartment   General     200
Apartment     SBI       200
Apartment     BOB       150
villa       General     500
villa         SBI       400
villa         BOB       300
```

Problem: 1: The number of column is unknown (max 200) in the Excel sheet.

I have converted the Excel sheet to a XML document and have passed it as parameter to SQL Server.
Now how to use unknown column is the biggest problem.

If anyone has done this before, give a brief description how to do it.
xml is my `xmldocument`, I am passing this to my `BillingConfig procedure`.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("BillingConfig", con);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@info", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = xml.InnerXml;
```

Help appreciated

Comment: If it's an XML document - why aren't you using the `XML` datatype?

Comment: See: [Introduction to XQuery in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: If you post a sample of your XML I am sure someone could come up with a query that returns the rows like you want.

Comment: I can't guess your XML structure based on a table. Presumably your column names are node names in the XML or they might be attribute names or they could be represented in another way. You don't have to know what "columns" will be in the XML to get the column names from the XML but you have to know **how** they are represented in the XML. What does your XML look like?

Comment: If your source is a table and you want to get it into SQL, why not import it as a table or delimited text and transform it with an SQL PIVOT? Why must you go through XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `Cursor` in SqlServer.

1. Get all your column names using

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Attribute.Name.query('local-name(.)') AS VARCHAR(100))
   Columnname  FROM @xml.nodes('//@*') Attribute(Name)
   ```
2. Validate Columns
3. Apply Cursor on these to convert columns into rows

   ```
   DECLARE @id VARCHAR(10)
   declare @loc varchar(25)
   set @loc = '/MainItem/SubItem';

   declare @query varchar(max)        

   DECLARE myCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
       SELECT * FROM @tempcolumnname

   OPEN myCursor
   FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @id

   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
   BEGIN
      set @query = 'SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@hdoc, '+@loc+', 3) WITH (xyz int)'
      exec (@query)

      FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor INTO @id
   END
   ```